# Windows CLI tool to take full ownership of a file

Tags: windows, file-management, command-line, sysadmin

I do auditing of Windows Systems, I need a simple and robust CLI tool that can take ownership of any file to the full extent.

I've dabbled with *takeown* and *icacls* but they seem to be quite limited, especially with system files.

While I do have success most of the time, there are certain files that just won't budge.
And those files most of the time require the machine to be rebooted into a separate environment to actually make the changes needed.

Any tools like *chmod* that changes ALL permissions on a resource, not just partial entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thorough research I've come up with this script:

```
@echo off

rem Copyright (C) 2017-2023 Nurudin Imsirovic
rem ownfile - Take full ownership of a resource
rem Created: 2017-04-21 11:23 AM
rem Updated: 2023-08-16 04:49 PM

rem Developer notes
rem
rem  takeown's /SKIPSL option only applies
rem  if recursion is used.  Meaning that
rem  setting the ownership on a symlink
rem  will affect its target.

set file=%1
set recursive=%2
set skip_symlinks=%3
set quiet=%4

if /I [%file%] equ [] goto usage

set suffix_t=
set suffix_i=

if [%recursive%] equ [1] (
    set suffix_t=/d y /r
    set suffix_i=/T
)

if [%skip_symlinks%] equ [1] (
    set suffix_t=%suffix_t% /SKIPSL
    set suffix_i=%suffix_i% /L
)

if [%quiet%] equ [1] (
    set suffix_t=%suffix_t% ^>nul 2^>^&1
    set suffix_i=%suffix_i% ^>nul 2^>^&1
)

goto process

:process
@takeown /f %file% /a %suffix_t%
@takeown /f %file% %suffix_t%
@icacls %file% /grant Administrators:(F,MA) /c %suffix_i%
@icacls %file% /grant Users:(F,MA) /c %suffix_i%
@icacls %file% /grant SYSTEM:(F,MA) /c %suffix_i%
@icacls %file% /grant "LOCAL SERVICE":(F,MA) /c %suffix_i%
@icacls %file% /grant "NETWORK SERVICE":(F,MA) /c %suffix_i%
@icacls %file% /grant "RESTRICTED":(F,MA) /c %suffix_i%
@icacls %file% /grant "ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES":(F,MA) /c %suffix_i%
@icacls %file% /grant "ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES":(F,MA) /c %suffix_i%
@icacls %file% /grant TrustedInstaller:(F,MA) /c %suffix_i%
@icacls %file% /setintegritylevel L /c %suffix_i%
@icacls %file% /inheritance:r /c %suffix_i%
@icacls %file% /inheritance:d /c %suffix_i%
@icacls %file% /setowner "%username%" /c %suffix_i%
@icacls %file% /grant "%username%":(F,MA) /c %suffix_i%
goto exit

:usage
echo.ownfile ^<file^> ^<recursive^> ^<skip symlinks^> ^<quiet^>
goto exit

:exit
exit /B 0
```

If the script is outdated you may find the latest changes [here](https://gist.github.com/oxou/32f1c20154b3733f8a4015d4599f295f).

I don't know how good of an idea this is but it works for me.

Comment: Please post the script here

Comment: I've referenced the link in case I make changes.

Comment: You should still post the script here, in case you randomly remove GH account or repository. Answers should be as self-sufficient as possible.

Comment: @Destroy666 Done

Comment: Sounds like this script does not only take ownership but also grants permissions to almost everyone. I'm not sure, but the script may only work on English systems.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Yes, I usually work with system files and this is required for those. Regarding languages I can't confirm as I only run English.